# Query result into field

Tags: ms-access

I have a query set up as such:

```
SELECT tblOrderItems.Quantity * tblItem.Price AS result
 FROM tblOrderItems
LEFT JOIN tblItem
   ON tblOrderItems.Pizza_Code = tblItem.ItemCode
```

How do I make it so that the 'result' at the end of the query is displayed in the field tblOrderItems.Line Price

Comment: I want to make it so the result of the above query is displayed in a field known as tblOrderItems.Item Price

Comment: I am getting a 'Syntax error in FROM clause.' error

Comment: The code is as follows:                                                                            `SELECT tblOrderItems.Quantity * tblPizza.Price                                   AS result
     FROM tblOrderItems
    UPDATE tblOrderItems INNER JOIN tblPizza
          ON tblOrderItems.Pizza_Code = tblPizza.PizzaCode
     SET tblOrderItems.Line Price = tblOrderItems.Quantity * tblPizza.Price`

Comment: `Line Price` is an additional field in tbl.OrderItems. I want that to display the result of the query.

Comment: `UPDATE` is an action query, it updates the value of `Line Price`. the syntax is just as I wrote in the answer

Comment: Do I place this in a new query or add it to the existing query?

Comment: In a new query, or replace the existing one. If the `SELECT` query has a name, you can use it in the `UPDATE` to avoid double calculations... What name did you give the query?

Comment: Excuse me... With no `ItemCode` in `qryLinePrice` you cant join it... just stick to the Update query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE tblOrderItems LEFT JOIN tblItem
   ON tblOrderItems.Pizza_Code = tblItem.ItemCode
SET tblOrderItems.[Line Price] = tblOrderItems.Quantity * tblItem.Price
```